# VBA Macro to combine two sheets based on common ID number number using Match Function or VLookUp

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine data from two sheets (sheet 1 & 2) in a MS Excel 2003 workbook. Each sheet contains ID numbers in column A. However, the data contained in Sheet 1 may have the same ID number multiple times.

For example:

Sheet 1

| ID# | Owner Name | Property Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Bill F | ABA |
| 101 | Bill F | CHC |
| 102 | Jane G | DFD |

Sheet 2

| ID# | Address | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Main St. | MI |
| 102 | Grey Pl. | CA |

Ref: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-to-combine-two-sheets-based-on-common-id-number.833381/

And I found the following code can work, but the running speed is slow when a number of cells is more than 100k because it uses `Cells.Find` function. Now, I want to enhance the code by changing `.Find` to Vlookup or Match or Index Match.

VBA is must. Excel formula is not allowed.

```
Sub MatchIDs()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Dim ID As Range
    Dim foundID As Range
    For Each ID In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        Set foundID = Sheets("TestGrid").Range("A:A").Find(ID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundID Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & ID.Row & ":U" & ID.Row).Copy Sheets("TestGrid").Range("Q" & foundID.Row)
        End If
    Next ID
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "VBA is a must - Excel formula not allowed" - what about `WorksheetFunction`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction - it allows you to get the results of excel formulas without actually writing them in the spreadsheet

Comment: @Spencer Barnes. If you think the code significantly enhances the code performance, then Worksheet Function is okay.

Comment: @SpencerBarnes Could you write me the code? because i am still a beginner of VBA. I want to learn how to use combine Worksheetfunction to my code

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
Sub MatchIDs()
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Only uncomment the above line when you're sure it all works
    Dim SearchRow As Long, FindRow As Long
    With WorksheetFunction
        On Error Resume Next
        For SearchRow = 2 To Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            FindRow = 0
            FindRow = .Match(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(SearchRow, 1), Sheets("TestGrid").Range("A:A"), 0)
                If FindRow > 0 Then Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & SearchRow & ":U" & SearchRow).Copy Sheets("TestGrid").Range("Q" & FindRow)
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

See if that's any quicker.

Comment: The code doesn't have bug, but it doesn't generate result

Comment: Try using f8 to go through it line-by-line and see which line isn't behaving?